# Will Riemann Hypothesis, if true, give us the exact value of number of primes less than a given number?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-hypothesis

As we know that RH is the most popular unsolved problem in all of maths. If this hypothesis is true, then will it give us the power to predict the exact number of primes less then a given number? And how it will effect the e-commerce system?

Comment: There are ways to find the exact number of primes below a given bound. The simplest way is to just count one-by-one. I suppose you ask whether RH provides a _fast_ or an _effective_ way to do this. To my knowledge, RH doesn't let us do anything like that; it just provides strong asymptotic bounds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Prime Number Theorem states that $\pi(x)$, the number of primes up to a number $x$, is $$\pi\left(x\right)=\textrm{Li}\left(x\right)+O\left(x\exp\left(-C\sqrt{\log\left(x\right)}\right)\right)$$ where $C>0$ and $\textrm{Li}\left(x\right)$ is the [logarithmic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function) of $x$. Now if the Riemann Hypothesis is true, then you can take $$\pi\left(x\right)=\textrm{Li}\left(x\right)+O\left(\sqrt{x}\log\left(x\right)\right)$$ and this is, essentially, the best possible. So you haven't the exact number but a better approximation.

Comment: Is it the best approximation that we can achieve?

Comment: Essentially, yes. This follows from the explicit formula of $\psi(x)$. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExplicitFormula.html